# It doesn't give anthing. Can someone help me about dictionaries and objects and classes in python?

Tags: python, list, class, dictionary, error-handling

I am trying to print frequencies of all words in a text.
I wanna print all keys according to their sorted values.
Namely, I wanna print the frequencies from most frequent to least frequent.
Here is my code:

```
freqMap = {}
class analysedText(object):

    def __init__(self, text):
        # remove punctuation
        formattedText = text.replace('.', '').replace('!', '').replace('?', '').replace(',', '')

        # make text lowercase
        formattedText = formattedText.lower()

        self.fmtText = formattedText

    def freqAll(self):

        wordList = self.fmtText.split(' ')


        freqMap = {}
        for word in set(wordList):
            freqMap[word] = wordList.count(word)

        return freqMap


mytexte = str(input())
my_text = analysedText(mytexte)
my_text.freqAll()
freqKeys = freqMap.keys()
freqValues = sorted(freqMap.values())
a = 0
for i in freqValues:
    if i == a:
        pass
    else:
        for key in freqKeys:
            if freqMap[key] == freqValues[i]:
                print(key,": ", freqValues[i])
        a = i
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`freqAll` method of your class does `return` `freqMap` which you should store but do not do that, therefore you are in fact processing empty dict `freqMap`, which was created before class declaration. Try replacing

```
my_text.freqAll()
```

using

```
freqMap = my_text.freqAll()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function `freqAll` returns a value that you are not catching.
It should be:

```
counts = my_text.freqAll()
```

Then you use the counts variable in the rest of your code.